# MySQL: How to find products repeatedly ordered by customers in different orders

Tags: mysql

I had tried a lot but when could not find a solution only then I posted my first question here:

I have four tables:

```
    products
    ---------------
    id, name

    customers
    ------------------
    id, name

    orders
    -------------
    id, customer_id

    orders_products
    ---------------------------
    id, order_id, product_id
```

Certainly, a customer can order a product only once in an order

In one query, I want to return each customer_id along with order_id and product_id who has ordered any product in more than one order.

In other words, for every customer I want to find different products ordered by a customer more than once (in separate orders), along with product_id and order_id. So product_id/order_id should repeat in result as product will be ordered more than once in more than one order. I don't want to return record where product is ordered only once.

I hope I am clear enough.

I already had sample data and tables. Editing my question to post sql for creating database and tables:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `test`
USE `test`;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7;

INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
    (1, 'Car'),
    (2, 'Bus'),
    (3, 'Truck'),
    (4, 'Fan'),
    (5, 'Photo'),
    (6, 'Watch');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6;

INSERT INTO `customers` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
    (1, 'Sukh'),
    (2, 'Sukh2'),
    (3, 'Ravi'),
    (4, 'Ravinder'),
    (5, 'Jas');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8;


INSERT INTO `orders` (`id`, `customer_id`) VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 2),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 2),
    (5, 5),
    (6, 4),
    (7, 1);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order_products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7;

INSERT INTO `order_products` (`id`, `order_id`, `product_id`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 2, 1),
    (3, 1, 2),
    (4, 4, 1),
    (5, 3, 5),
    (6, 7, 5);


select p.name, c.name, o.id as order_id, c.id as customer_id, p.id as product_id
from customers c inner join orders o on c.id=o.customer_id
inner join order_products op on op.order_id=o.id
inner join products p on p.id=op.product_id order by order_id
```

sukh2 has ordered car in order_id 2 and 4 (car ordered by one customer more than once) so I want to return both the records,
sukh has ordered photo in order_id 3 and 7 (photo ordered by one customer more than once) so those two should also be returned in total 4 records.

I tried lots of variations of below query but was not getting correct results. I guess only thing I missed was joining with customer_id on sub query result. So I tried below given query and it does seem to work. @barmar suggestion helped.

```
SELECT p.name, c.name, o.id AS order_id, c.id AS customer_id, p.id AS product_id
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN orders o ON c.id=o.customer_id
INNER JOIN order_products op ON op.order_id=o.id
INNER JOIN products p ON p.id=op.product_id
INNER JOIN (
SELECT customer_id, p.id AS product_id
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN orders o ON c.id=o.customer_id
INNER JOIN order_products op ON op.order_id=o.id
INNER JOIN products p ON p.id=op.product_id
GROUP BY c.id, p.id
HAVING COUNT(p.id) > 1) q2 ON q2.product_id=p.id AND q2.customer_id=c.id
```

Can it be written better? It's late at night. I'll try more and post if results are not right.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Please add some sample data to your question and provide the desired result.

Comment: Join with a query that returns `COUNT(*)` grouped by customer and product IDs, and select only the ones where the count is more than 1.

Comment: It's a little unusual to count the thing you're grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the joined tables in the subquery to `orders` and `order_products`, since they already hold all needed information (`customer_id` and `product_id`). You can also use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(p.id)`.

```
SELECT p.name, c.name, o.id AS order_id, c.id AS customer_id, p.id AS product_id
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN orders o ON c.id=o.customer_id
INNER JOIN order_products op ON op.order_id = o.id
INNER JOIN products p ON p.id = op.product_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT o.customer_id, op.product_id
    FROM  orders o 
    INNER JOIN order_products op ON op.order_id = o.id
    GROUP BY o.customer_id, op.product_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) q2 ON q2.product_id = p.id AND q2.customer_id = c.id
```

This will return the same as your query.

```
name    product_id  name    customer_id     order_id
Car              1  Sukh2             2            2
Car              1  Sukh2             2            4
Photo            5  Sukh              1            3
Photo            5  Sukh              1            7
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bq2WbLNGdKHGjowkR25VAr/0

However, if you can live with a slightly different data format, you can avoid the subquery and joins with same tables utilizing the `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregate function.

```
SELECT p.name, op.product_id, c.name, o.customer_id, GROUP_CONCAT(o.id) AS order_ids
FROM  orders o 
INNER JOIN order_products op ON op.order_id = o.id
INNER JOIN customers c ON c.id = o.customer_id
INNER JOIN products p on p.id = op.product_id
GROUP BY o.customer_id, op.product_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Result:

```
name    product_id  name    customer_id     order_ids
Photo            5  Sukh              1     7,3
Car              1  Sukh2             2     4,2
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n1zvoPjpBVAW9yvjPH1fro/0

But for better performance it can still make sense to do the aggregation in a subquery, thus reducing the size of the rows which need to be sorted for GROUP BY. So I would probably write the query this way:

```
SELECT p.name, q.product_id, c.name, q.customer_id, q.order_ids
FROM (
    SELECT o.customer_id, op.product_id, GROUP_CONCAT(o.id) order_ids
    FROM  orders o 
    INNER JOIN order_products op ON op.order_id = o.id
    GROUP BY o.customer_id, op.product_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) q
INNER JOIN products p ON p.id = q.product_id
INNER JOIN customers c ON c.id = q.customer_id
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v7xXW1cLgwAUR4DSGAomev/0

Comment: Thank you for your help. I needed result for each order so first query will do. I wanted to add other tables in the sub query because user may search by customer and product name so I can add where conditions to both sub and outer query. For performance reason:
1. Will it be better to conditionally inner join in sub query with the products and customers table if product and/or customer name are searched, and add it to where clause of sub query and outer query both. Or
2. Leave the sub query as it is without joining with products and customers and add where condition to only outer query.

Comment: @Sukh Better to filter in the subquery. It will reduce the number of rows, which have to be sorted. Actually you will end up with your original query, when you want to add WHERE conditions on customer and product names :-)

Comment: It just skipped my mind that adding filters to only subquery should be enough. Thank you again. Just one last question, what difference it will make if I do count(*) or count(p.id)